# vector of functions that follow a pattern in R

Tags: r

I have an R question. I want to make vector functions that follow a pattern, in this case how create a vector like `v=(1/(x+1) , 1/(x+2), 1/(x+3),....,1/(x+n))` and to use each function independently, for example , the value of the first function is the first component of the vector v, evaluated in 3.

This should show 1/(3+1)=1/4

notice the vector components : 1/(x+i), i=1,...,n

How to create a "for" loop  v = (f1,f2,...fn) ,  fn=1/(x+i)
and then be able to call one of the functions?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list to store the functions in:

```
> v=list()
```

Create a function generator (you must use the force here):

```
> makef=function(i){force(i);function(x){1/(x+i)}}
```

Fill the list:

```
> for(i in 1:6){v[[i]]=makef(i)}
```

Call it thus:

```
> v[[1]](1)   
[1] 0.5     # 1/(1+1)
> v[[2]](1)
[1] 0.3333333   # 1/(2+1)
```

Comment: or `lapply(1:6,makef)` [I know the OP asked for a loop].  I like "you must use the [F]orce" ...

Answer (score 0):

In R you can add sequences to constants and get compact code.

```
 cont_fract <- function(x, length) { 1/(x+1:length) }

 cont_fract(3, 10)
#-----------
 [1] 0.25000 0.20000 0.16667 0.14286 0.12500 0.11111 0.10000
 [8] 0.09091 0.08333 0.07692
```

Josh's comment would apply here: If only doing this interactively could use `1/(3+1:10)`. For-loops are consideredless desirable in R since they tend to get in the way of thinking "vectorially", a strategy for which there has been extra effort at improving performance.